# How to give a user a role after bot message?

Tags: discord.js

Good Day. I'm testing a command that when the user type (prefix)+(keyword), then the user command the other bot where the OB sends an embedded message in which my code will the detect a keyword from OB then add the role to the user. Here's the code for reference

```js
let prefix = ("/")

client.on('message', (message) => {

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command == "e"){
        let en = args[0]
        if(!en){
            return message.channel.send("type title or player");
        }
        else{
            if (message.author.id === '555955826880413696') {
                if (message.embeds.length == 1) {
                    const embed = message.embeds[0]
                    if (en === embed.title.includes("title") || embed.title.includes  ("player")){

                        let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("805992874566090762");

                        message.member.roles.add(role);

                        setTimeout(function(){
                            message.member.roles.remove(role);
                            return  message.channel.send('test success')
                        }, 5000);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I can't seem to trigger the **else** statement but the **if(!en)** works fine

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBKYG.png)

Comment: `en === embed.title.includes("title")` I think this could be your problem as that's checking if `en` is `true`, rather than just checking if the embed's title is "title"

Comment: Can you give more details? I can barely understand.

Comment: I've added an image for reference. Supposedly the user type `/e title` then the bot will provide a confirmation message (which i've not yet added) and waits for the user to command the other bot. As the user command the ob, the code will check if the ob's embedded message has the value of `en` which is **title** in which the bot the will mute the user for a certain duration. Sorry for the long explanation since i'm not quite adept in english yet

Comment: What Dinty mentioned is correct, at least as part of the problem you are experiencing. I cannot tell how to fully solve your problem because even with the image and your explanation, it is still very difficult to understand what you mean. It is also impossible to tell what you are actually trying to do and/or how you are doing it from just the code you've provided. We need a more detailed and more specific explanation to properly address this issue.